# php_oci8.dll - Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, php-extension, oracle-call-interface

I have Windows 7 64bit, IIS 7, and installed PHP on IIS. I enabled php_oci8.dll for Oracle connection, but I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5\ext\php_oci8.dll' - 
The specified module could not be found.
in Unknown on line 0
```

I have checked that the php_oci8.dll exist in: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5\ext\php_oci8.dll'

My php.ini below:

```
extension_dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5\ext\"
[PHP_OCI8]
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

I downloaded Oracle Instant Client 32 bit at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html. Then I extract the it and set the directory in Environment Variable "Path".

However I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `[PHP_OCI8]` is not a valid .ini file section. There is a `[OCI8]` section, but you don't need to put the extension line there. What version of PHP are you using (5.3, 5.4, 5.5)? Is it 32- or 64-bit?  what version of the IntantClient are you using?

Comment: [OCI8] is automatically inserted by PHP Manager in IIS. I'm using PHP 5.5 64 bit, Instant Client version 10 32 bit. I have solve it by installing a higher Instant Client version 11. Thank for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the fix, I should install instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.3.0.zip 32bit. Earlier I installed the Oracle Client version 10. I tried to install the version 10 first because it worked when I install it in PHP 5.5/ IIS 8 / Windows 2012 Server. So it's weird why the IIS 8 in PHP 5.5 accepts Instant Client 10, while IIS 7 in PHP 5.5 doesn't accept Instant Client 10, but needs Oracle Instant Client 11. So the lesson is to try different  Oracle Instant Client versions. Thanks.